# Understanding threading

Tags: python

Trying to get my head around threading. In my code, it's only firing one thread, when I think it should go straight on to the second. I've been reading about locks and allocating but don't quite understand. What would I need to do here to let 2 threads run independently at the same time?

```
import thread

def myproc(item):
    print("Thread fired for " + item)
    while True:
        pass

things = ['thingone', 'thingtwo']

for thing in things:
    try:
        thread.start_new_thread(myproc(thing))

    except:
        print("Error")
```

Comment: You'll need to show actual and expected output for anybody to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got the signature to `start_new_thread` wrong. You're calling `myproc` and passing the result as an argument to `start_new_thread`, which never happens as `myproc` never terminates.

Instead, it should be:

```
thread.start_new_thread(myproc, (thing,) )
```

The first argument is the function (ie. the function object, not calling the function) and the second is a tuple of arguments.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread

Once you have your program actually starting both threads, you probably want to add a pause at the end because the threads will terminate when the main thread finishes.

Also, please consider using the `threading` module instead of the `thread` module, as it provides a much nicer higher level interface, such as a convenient way for waiting until your threads have finished executing.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#module-threading

Comment: The script also quits before the threads have the opportunity to print anything

Comment: The original script in the question didn't - it didn't get as far as starting the threads. But yes, that is a concern when you fix the original problem.

Comment: Brilliant - that makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

Your application quits before the second thread has had time to finish, from what I can tell.

You need to wait for both of your threads to finish before your application terminates, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import thread
import time

# Define a function for the thread
def print_time(threadName, delay):
   count = 0
   while count < 5:
      time.sleep(delay)
      count += 1
      print "%s: %s" % ( threadName, time.ctime(time.time()) )

# Create two threads as follows
try:
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-1", 2, ) )
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-2", 4, ) )
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"

while 1: # This is a bad solution due to the busy wait loop. More below.
   pass
```

You should preferrably store the thread objects and use `thread1.join()` and `thread2.join()` at the end before quitting to signal that they have both terminated.

Comment: This is useful too - how would I go about storing the threads when they are created in a loop? I would need to get the variable 'thing' into the instance name somehow?

Comment: @user4893295 See this page http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm under "Creating Thread Using Threading Module" for information on how to store a thread object!